# Is Chain of Rep. appropriate or not

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, recursion

I was asked in an interview to implement a business rule

Requirements change. They always do:

> 1. assess a 20% fee for any amount below $100,000.
> 2. assess a 10% fee for any amount between $100,000 and $500,000.
> 3. assess a 5% fee for any amount above $500,000

Calculate the fee for an arbitrary amount x.

Example: Given a $600,000 invoice the fee should be $65,000.

Given a $50,000 invoice the fee should be $10,000.

Given a $200,000 invoice the fee should be $30,000.

I used CofR but the interviewer then asked what if their is more than 3 conditions like n of them would i create n-classes to handle each request.

Is their a better approach to the question asides writing a very long recursive function checking for each of the conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoR is helpful when the members of the chain have substantially different rules, but in this case, all of the rules are basically the same (charge a certain percent if the amount is over X). Instead of independent classes, just have one struct-like class that holds the minimum amount and percentage, and another one that looks up the appropriate fee:

```
class FeeSchedule {
    static class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
        int threshold;
        int percentage;

        int compareTo(Entry other) {
            // sort by percentage, descending
        }

    SortedSet<Entry> feeTable;

    int calculateFee(int invoiceAmount) {
        for(Entry e : feeTable)
            if(invoiceAmount > e.threshold)
                return (invoiceAmount * e.percentage);

        // error condition; return 0?
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome logic you have got here, but how would i get the percentage out for each of the entry. I can't seem to reach a conclusion on that.

Comment: @Ayodeji This is a basic sketch. Getters, constructors, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the interviewer was implying that something like the chain-of-responsibility pattern would be a little over-engineered for a problem like this.  There's also an argument that your implementing classes would actually have the same responsibility, in that they'd all be computing an amount based on a given input, just with different parameters.

I would probably do this with two simple classes.  One would compute the percentage fee rate based on the input value and one would use this rate to return the fee amount.

If you need to add a fourth condition, you just add it to the class containing the rate computation.  I don't see why it needs to be any more complicated than this for such a simple problem.

**EDIT:**

I was thinking along the same lines as @chrylis in that there'd be a class to perform the calculation by processing an ordered list of rates.

```
class Rate {
    int rangeSize;
    double commission;

    Rate(int rangeSize, double commission){
        this.rangeSize = rangeSize;
        this.commission = commission;
    }

    int computeForAmount(int amount) {
        if (amount <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (int) (Math.min(amount, this.rangeSize) * this.commission);
    }
}

class FeeCalculator {

    List<Rate> rates = Arrays.asList(
            new Rate(100, 0.2),
            new Rate(400, 0.1),
            new Rate(500, 0.05));

    int calculateCommission(int startingAmount) {
        int commission = 0;
        int remainingAmount = startingAmount;

        for (Rate rate : this.rates) {
            commission += rate.computeForAmount(remainingAmount);
            remainingAmount -= rate.rangeSize;
        }

        return commission;
    }

}
```

I admit that I'm not entirely happy about breaking the encapsulation by calling `rate.rangeSize` but it does demonstrate the design I was trying to articulate.

Comment: Can you please put down your explanation in a pseudocode or something, i don't seem to understand the logic you presented. Thanks.

Comment: I see, this totally takes away my recursion and makes it more object oriented than procedural. @chrylis point is now more clearer. Thanks guy. New addition to the bag.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple strategy pattern should be enough in this case. Something like:

```
interface FeeAssessor {
    public double assessFee(double invoice);
}

FeeAssessor feeAssessor = new FeeAssessor() {
        // logic goes here
    };

double calculateFee(double invoice) {
    return feeAssessor.assessFee(invoice);
}
```

For a simple business logic that you presented, I think it would be simpler to implement it all inside one `assessFee()` function. You can implement different (simple) ones and swap out the "strategy" object as needed. If the fee assessment algorithm depends on multiple varying factors that are **independent** of each other, then you can further split them up into multiple strategy methods.